# how to create a menu within an ng-grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-grid

we are really having problems finding a way on how to create a menu within an ng-grid.
Something similar to the ECB block within share point.

So, there would be a button that when clicked would show options for that particular row.

We may be looking in the wrong places, but we can't find any help or examples on the internet..

Answer (score 1):

As I told you few days ago you should use row and celltemplates to achieve something like this.

Here is the changed code to better match the current state of your question:

```
    $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    rowTemplate: '<div   ng-style="{\'cursor\': row.cursor, \'z-index\': col.zIndex() }" ' +
      'ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" ' +
      'class="ngCell {{col.cellClass}}" ng-cell></div>' +
      '<div ng-show="showmenu" class="hmenu">' +
      '<ul>' +
      '<li><button ng-click="viewme(row.entity.name)">View</button></li>' +
      '<li><button ng-click="editme(row.entity.name)">Edit</button></li>' +
      '</ul>' +
      '</div>',
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'name',
      displayName: 'Name'
    }, {
      field: 'age',
      displayName: 'Age',
      cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}' +
        '<span  ng-click="$parent.showmenu=!$parent.showmenu"><button>click me</button></span>' +
        '</div>'
    }]
    };
```

True, this is no beauty, but it shows you how to go on. Do your styling in style.css and the row template. This is the best I can do with my weekend laptop.

[Here is the Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZOvZzXIPKvUNtIbZkwRb?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially set each CellTemplate to have its own ng-if/ng-show block that's hidden/shown based on a variable on your `row.entity` object.  Then, when your function fires for the selection of the row, you can set that variable (`$scope.whatever`) to hide/show what's necessary.  On my phone at the moment, but I'll try to make a plnkr/jsfiddle later.

Comment: Thank you. It would be great to see your sample. We have been struggling with this for a couple of days now